# How do I convert each line elements into an Array, So I can select only one element like data[2]

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, indexing, foreach

here is my code, I have received data from firebase storage.

```
listRef.listAll().then((res) => {
  res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
    // All the prefixes under listRef.
    // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
  });
  res.items.forEach((itemRef, index) => {
    itemRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      console.log(`${index} ${url}`)
    })
  });
})
```

Here is my output result like 
`0 https://myfirebaseapp.com/videos/nice.mp4` 
`1 https://myfirebaseapp.com/videos/bad.mp4` 
`2 https://myfirebaseapp.com/videos/funny.mp4`  [ I want only this element instead of whole list ] 
`3 https://myfirebaseapp.com/videos/good.mp4` 
`4 https://myfirebaseapp.com/videos/sad.mp4`

Comment: What are all the properties of the itemRef? Is there any way to know that you want `https://myfirebaseapp.com/videos/funny.mp4` without having to call `itemRef.getDownloadURL()`?

Comment: @TomFaltesek Yes, these are the properties and methods of itemRef -
bucket, child(), fullPath, getDownloadURL(), list(), listAll(), name, parent, put, putString(), root, storage, toString()  .

Comment: Are you able to know if the `funny.mp4` is the one you want given the `fullPath` or `name` properties?

Comment: @TomFaltesek the output is not an Array. The output is in multilines 'string'. Is there any way to convert each lines into an Array so I can select like data[2]

Comment: In my example below, I've attempted to select the item before having to call `getDownloadURL()`. Then we can hopefully avoid invoking that awaitable function in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`find()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on your array. Here's an example:

```js
var items = [
  'https://myfirebaseapp.com/videos/nice.mp4',
  'https://myfirebaseapp.com/videos/bad.mp4',
  'https://myfirebaseapp.com/videos/funny.mp4',
  'https://myfirebaseapp.com/videos/good.mp4',
  'https://myfirebaseapp.com/videos/sad.mp4'
]

var funny = items.find(x => x.endsWith('funny.mp4'));

console.log(funny);
```

For your code, it might look something like this:

```js
listRef.listAll().then((res) => {
  ...

  // Find the string that ends with 'funny.mp4'.
  var funnyItem = res.items.find(x => x.fullPath.endsWith('funny.mp4'));

  if(funnyItem) {
    // The item we want was found. Do something with it...
    funnyItem.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      console.log(`Fetching ${url}...`);
    });
  }
})
```

The above example will work if we don't know the location of `funny.mp4`. If you know for sure that the location of the item you want is always going to be 2, then you *could* get away with doing this:

```js
listRef.listAll().then((res) => {
  ...

  res.items[2].getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
    console.log(`Fetching ${url}...`);
  });
})
```

If you really just need a collection of the download URLs (hard to tell from your question), then you can project your items array with the `map` function like this:

```js
listRef.listAll().then(async (res) => {
  ...

  var urls = await res.items.map(async x => Promise.all(await x.getDownloadURL()));
  console.log(`Fetching ${urls[2]}...`);
})
```

Keep in mind that this will invoke the awaitable `getDownloadURL()` method on every item, which is probably undesired.

Comment: Solved. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You should put an if statement inside the `forEach`, checking on the index (if you generically want the 3rd element of the list) or on the name of the video (if you want specifically that video)